# What is better approach to display in swagger-ui List parametrizied interface?

Tags: spring, swagger-ui, springfox, springdoc-openapi-ui

I use springdoc for describing API. I have the this request body

```
  class SearchRequest {
    val fields: List<Field>? = null
    var searchTerm: String? = null
    @Parameter(description = "Page number")
    var pageNumber: Int = 0
    @Parameter(description = "Page size", schema = Schema(type = "integer", defaultValue = "20"))
    var pageSize: Int = 20
}
```

which is used in Post method and annotated with @ParameterObject
all fields displayed as inputs in swagger-ui, except List. Field is an interface which is implemened by other classes

```
  interface Field {
    @get:Schema(description = "Field name")
    val name: String
    @get:Schema(description = "Field value")
    val value: Any
    @get:Schema(description = "Field type")
    val type: FieldType
  }
```

I want to display name, value, type as separate input fields in swagger-ui(or may be better approach exists), how can I do that?
[image]